# Checking for the existence of children when using ElementTree for XML parsing in python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, parsing, elementtree

I am using the ElementTree XML API in python3 and have a question, which seems to be basic, I just did not find in the documentation the right function to do it. The starting point is that I consider an xml file whose name is given in the string `name`. I am looking for a function that checks whether a chld exists. by its name. Currently what I am doing is:

```
     import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
     tree = ET.parse(name)
     root = tree.getroot()
     item = root.getchildren()[2]
```

because I know that the item I am looking in is in position 2 (the 3rd entry). But I would rather have something like:

```
     item = root.checkIfExists('itemName')
```

Can someone suggest a function for this? Or a better way to approach this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements):

> Element.findall() finds only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element. Element.find() finds the first child with a particular tag

So, try:

```
item = root.find('itemName')
```

[`.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements) returns `None` if no such element exists. `.findall()` returns an empty list in that case.

Demonstration:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.XML('<root><item1/><item2/><itemName/></root>')
assert root[2] is root.find('itemName')
```

Comment: Updated link for Py 3.10+ [here](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements).